# Why can't I catch EJB exceptions?

Tags: exception, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I can't seem to catch exceptions such as NoResultException or EJBException in my java ee 6 project.  Is there something I am doing wrong?  I have caught exceptions outside the EJB container but this is my first time using EJB.  Thanks.

```
@Stateless
public class UserEJB {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public String getUserName(User user) {
        return user.getName();
    }

    public User fetchUserByEmail(String email) {

        User user = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByEmail", User.class).setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult();
        return user;
    }

    public User fetchUserById(int id) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUserId", User.class).setParameter("userId", id).getSingleResult();
    }

    public List<User> fetchAllUsers() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("User.findAll", User.class).getResultList();
    }
}

@Named(value = "userController")
@RequestScoped
public class UserController {

    private User user = new User();
    @EJB
    UserEJB userEJB;
    @Inject
    SecurityController securityController;

    public UserController() {
    }

    public void login(ActionEvent event) {

        try {

             User userLogin = userEJB.fetchUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (userLogin.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            securityController.setIsLoggedIn(true);
            securityController.setIsAdmin(true);
            securityController.setUser(user);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the user
     */
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * @param user the user to set
     */
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the exception is not thrown, when you catch `Exception` and don't log it? catch (Exception e) {} Try writing `e.printStacktrace()`

Comment: Would you be able to add the stack trace from the glassfish log here?

Comment: The answer you accepted did solve your problem ? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you put two System.out.printlns in the code? One in the exception handler and one right before the if statement. What do you get?

Looking at the code I would say you would be able to catch the exception, which should be a JPA exception wrapped in an EJB one.

Comment: Well the code is running fine.  I just want to catch the EJBException and the NoResultException basically.

Comment: Maybe this is really a very simple case that the exception simply never has been thrown? If the code is running fine, no exceptions will be thrown. If no exceptions are being thrown, your code doesn't catch any. But this is very basic Java... I assume your problem is not -that- basic...

Comment: I understand.  But an exception is being thrown.  I can see it in the glassfish logs.  I am forcing it to be thrown because I am looking up a user that doesn't exist.  I will have a no result exception.  I have been able to catch this fine 100 times before.  It's moving to the EJB container that has change something.  Is there nothing special I need to change to allow me to catch exceptions?