# JavaEE EJB Can't catch TransactionRolledbackException

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, jpa, ejb

I am building a small JavaEE project and have a Repository Class:

```
@Stateless
public class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository<User> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public User getByName(String username) {
       CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = ...

       return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

and i have  Service class that uses this function:

```
@Stateless
public class UserService extends AbstractService<User> {
    public User getByName(String username) {
        try {
            return userRepository.getByName(username);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // says: "Caught: EJBTransactionRolledbackException"
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e.getClass());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the `catch (Throwable e)` clause to catch anything that might happen within this method, but apperently I'm wrong. I still get a `TransactionRolledbackException` in my logs . I read [Why can't I catch EJB exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339864/why-cant-i-catch-ejb-exceptions?rq=1) but there is no real answer to the question itself.

**Why is the `TransactionRolledbackException` still thrown and how can i prevent this?** Also, what does it have to do with the `EJBTransactionRolledbackException` that actually IS being caught?

I also tried catching the exception inside the `getByName` method and throw a custom exception, with no luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little Help from Sameer Mali I found out why the transaction was being rolled back. The tracelog then could be avoided by throwing an exception that has the `@ApplicationException` Annotation. Also, the Exception may not inherit from `Throwable`, but must inherit from `Exception` (which is only reasonable anyway). The code ended up like this:

```
public User getByName(String username) {
   CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = ...

   try {
       return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
   } catch (NoSuchResultException e){ // Note: this is a System Exception
       throw new NoSuchUserException(username);
   }
}
```

and

```
@ApplicationException
public class NoSuchUserException {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your source code 
UserService = EJB client 
UserRepository = EJB being called by client/to be invoked EJB 
As no Transaction attribute has been specified it defaults to REQUEIRED, thus transaction context is being propagated from UserService to UserRepository i.e. all the stuff is being executed in single transaction.

With some excerpts from EJB 3.1 specification page 386

> Method condition: Bean method runs in the context of the caller’s
>   transaction [Note A]. This case may happen with Required, Mandatory,
>   and Supports attributes.

your condition satisfies this

> Method exception: all other exceptions and errors

this basically means System exception is thrown which is your case (Application exception is another one in EJB, too much to explain)

most important part is following of container action

> Container’s action
>   Log the exception or error [Note B].
>  
>   Mark the transaction for rollback. 
>   Discard instance [Note C]. 
>   Throw javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException to client. [Note D]

Thus as per your source code UserService the client will recieve EJBTransactionRolledbackException
Please read the specification for better understanding.

I hope this answers your question.

Also, just in case if you want to catch the exception add try-catch clause around 
        em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
in UserRepository Class. This will also remove the exception tracelog you are getting.

Comment: When i catch the exception at `getSingleResult`, I have two options: Throw another exception (e.g. a custom one), which ends up in the exact same behaviour that it will be caught but the logs are spammed, or do nothing, in which case the Service will not notice anything of the error at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you call one EJB method from another, by default it will join the same transaction.  So the rollback will only occur in the outermost method.  You could change the outer method to use BMT instead of CMT, then you will have control of the transaction commit and handling the error.

You could also make the inner call use a new transaction if you want it to be independent.

Comment: i fear i don't understand this. Adding `TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` doesn't change anything, do you think you could give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

That happens due the default behavior of EJB is to use  (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRED) which will join all the invocation into a single transaction. Well, you can force to create another transaction using TransactionAttribute with the http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRES_NEW . It is good you take a very careful decision where you will start, join or start/new transaction (you can also force to have have a current transaction or make it not bound to any transaction (which can help for performance) ,for examples).

Regards,
Luan

Comment: As already mentioned in the other answer, adding `TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` to the inner method doesn't change anything. Is this the wrong spot to put it?

Also: why can't i catch the exception?